# PRO*C Why the sql user & password should be mentioned in make file

Tags: sql, linux

I have a wierd question and i am trying to backtrace to the root cause.

The scenario is, 
I have a bunch of c, cpp & Pro*C code scattered in multiple folders [huge # of files]. Dozens of make files. We regularly run the makefiles to create the latest executables when we change something in code/config/libs.

The problem is:
My SQL User id and passwords are expiring at regular intervals. 
These ID's are being used in make files and in Pro*C code to connect to DB. we have to regularly get them reset and it has become a problem requesting the same again and again.

The question is,
Why the SQL credentials are failing after getting them reset? 
On every reset, the ID works for 3 or 4 times, after which again the ID fails.

In Make files, the ID's are used to check the semantics. and the proc by default checks for syntactical errors. The exe cannot fail if the ID's are working. So why the ID's are getting failed. Please advice on how this could be fixed.

Should i reqeust the DBA to change any settings of this ID? Or could there be something in my code, which makes the ID's fail by tring wrongly. We copy the ID's into an env variable, which are being read by all EXE's. Could this be causing the problem? Should we take any precautions when using the data from an ENV variable? [The exe's work 3 times perfectly, after which the SQL ID fails.]

Please advice on what all precautions should be taken from my side.

Comment: This sounds like you have an incorrect password and it's locking the account due to 3 incorrect tries. This is very easy to do if you have a bit of code that opens connections to the database multiple times. You need to find for certain from your DBA whether the account is locked as it's not very clear from your explanation.

Comment: You are very Correct. There are hundreds of make files using a couple of dozens of sql user id's and passwords. Now, searching for the exact id, which is causing this problem would be a bit of challenge. Let me figure out on how this could be identified.

Comment: I guess it's too hard to alter all your code to use a single login configuration or use windows trusted authentication. Perhaps you could tell your boss that this is an example of 'technical debt' where you are wasting time due to a design issue that needs to be fixed.